# Training negative intent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Trying to train LUIS on 2 different intents with 2 different responses: 'I want to install software' Intent: installSoftware ...

'I cannot install software' ..Intent: softwareIssue.

I have tried using cannot/ not able to/ unable as one entity but LUIS is still getting confused between the 2 intents. Ideas?

Comment: Add more utterances(like 5/6 for each) for the intents that test. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

As Haritha said, you will need to label more utterances with syntax related to negative responses.

> I cannot install software. I can't install software. I'm unable to
>   install software. I'm not able to install software. It won't install
>   software.

I recommend at least a dozen utterances for any intent before testing.

Another thing you can consider (if you're fine with setting up another API call) is using the Text Analytics API or another service that provides Sentiment Analysis.